DateFormatter fixed vs. current locale results in different localized strings in Swift
My issue is most easily described by code and the respective output:
print("\(Locale(identifier: "de_CH").identifier)") // prints de_CH
let explicitLocaleFormatter = DateFormatter()
explicitLocaleFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "de_CH")
explicitLocaleFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HHmm")
print("\(explicitLocaleFormatter.string(from: date))") // prints 19:01
        

print("\(Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.identifier)") // prints de_CH
let autoLocaleFormatter = DateFormatter()
autoLocaleFormatter.locale = Locale.current
autoLocaleFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("HHmm")
print("\(autoLocaleFormatter.string(from: date))") // prints 7:01 PM

How is this even possible? With the same locale, I get different outputs. Clearly, hardcoding the locale is not what I want, so how can I get the correct format but use the current locale?

A locale is more than just "de_CH". If you just want to extract that part from the current locale, perhaps Locale(languageComponents: .init(language: Locale.current.language)) will do?

That said, I can't actually reproduce your results.

Locale, as mentioned, is a lot of properties. Print the .hourCycle property of the two Locale's in your code and they should be different. Another thing is, I believe, when using current or autoUpdating the device settings will be considered.

If you go to Settings app, “General” » “Language & Region” and scroll to the bottom, does the “Region Format Example” show a 24h clock or 12h clock with am/pm? From what you describe, it sounds like your particular device is configured for 12h clock whereas the de_CH default is 24h clock.

Set format directly "HH:mm" without template.

I can't imagine why you want to display time as "19:01" if user set in his settings 12hour format.

A Locale is more than just a language code and region code. It has many more Components, including hourCycle.
Although I cannot reproduce your results, autoupdatingCurrent and current are indeed "special" Locale instances. You can try creating copies of the current locale (which will not be special anymore), like this:
Locale(components: Locale.Components(locale: Locale.current))

You can also copy only some parts of the components. For example, if you want to ignore the user's preferred hour cycle and use the locale's default hour cycle,
var comps = Locale.Components(locale: Locale.current)
comps.hourCycle = nil
let copy = Locale(components: comps)


Thanks for the response! Unfortunately Components are only available on iOS 16, whereas we need to support also iOS 15. I see now that they are not necessarily the same, but what could cause them (and in particular this property) to be different?

@ambassador the user settings. They can change a lot of locale settings in the settings app. You can also try just copying the identifier, i.e. Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier).
